# Django Admin - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, nginx

Whenever I try to login to Django's admin app, after filling in username and password and submitting the form, the page hangs forever.

When I refresh the POST request in the browser, I get:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

[image]

When I refresh the page again, everything works, I see admin app, I am logged in and I can go and do CRUD operations on my apps and tables.

Any ideas why?

I have Nginx reverse proxy in front of the Django app doing https handshake. So when you go to (example):

```
https://platform.staging.com/admin/
```

Nginx reverse proxies that to

```
http://admin1.staging.platform.com/admin/
```

This is my nginx config:

```
upstream admin-cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server admin1.staging.platform.com;
}

# force redirect of http to https
# application will be available only over https
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name platform.staging.com;
  rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

# https server
# traffic is going to local web servers over normal http
# front nginx proxy server will hold ssl session
server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;
  server_name platform.staging.com;
  keepalive_timeout 70;

  ssl                 on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/platform.staging.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/platform.staging.com.key;

  location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://admin-cluster;
  }

}
```

EDIT:

So, I found a workaround. When I allow also port 80 on my Nginx reverse proxy but redirect all http requests to https like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name platform.staging.com;
  rewrite     ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

It fixed the problem. Any idea why?

Comment: See edit at the end of my question for a workaround I implemented for now.

Answer (score 6):

Check your settings for values overriding the `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` values, as the problem could be related to the CSRF cookie. **EDIT**: I have in fact these two values set to True.

Also, check your [`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) setting, although I'm not sure it has relation with your problem. I am missing a proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol directive in your nginx conf file used for letting Django know that you are passing through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have converted into https, have defined `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` in my settings.py then my Host proxy header from my nginx has a port like `proxy_header Host $host:$server_port`.